# compare two avx2 float arrays, write result to epi8

Tags: assembly, x86-64, avx2

I want to accomplish the following operation sequence in AVX2:

ymm13 has a vector of floats (of the same value)
ymm14 has a vector of floats (of different values)

I want to compare ymm13 and ymm14, and write results to 8 int8/epi8 types into another ymm register, say ymm12. I want to be able to specify which quarter of the ymm12 the result should go into.

I figure you would do it using vcmpltps, which will return a full ymm, and then somehow fetch the first byte of each four-byte group in the ymm using a swizzle or something.

Any suggestions?

**For the purpose of this question, let's assume that we can actually join four comparisons.**

Comment: You could use `vpackssdw` and `vpacksswb` for this.

Comment: What shall be in the other quarters? Do you actually want to join the results of 4 comparisons? The biggest hurdle is that in AVX2 all swizzle operations on types smaller than 32 bits only work inside 128 bit lanes (this includes `vpackssdw` and `vpacksswb`).

Comment: Yes. you can join 4 comparisons. My main reservation is that this will take a lot of vector registers. the 4 comparisons would need 8 registers just to store the things, and another register to hold the result. Other parts of my program are thus restricted to only 7 registers.

Comment: The compiler (or your hand-written code?) can do a couple compares and combine before doing more; you don't have to have all 8 compare inputs sitting in registers before you start comparing and combining.  Out-of-order exec can take care of hiding a bit of latency to pipeline things.  Also, are you sure you need byte elements?  Could you usefully `vpmovmskb eax, ymm0` to get a compare result bitmap?  Then maybe `mov [rdi], al` to  store to a bitmap in memory.  (That's somewhat more expensive to unpack back into a vector later, vs. `vpmovsxbd`, but

Comment: I need per byte elements because i need to compute on those bytes. Unfortunately AVX doesn't have instructions that operate on binary data type

Comment: Ok, then yeah you want to pack in pairs.  If order of the packed data isn't important (as long as it's all there), possibly *blend* words with `vpblendw` instead of one of the pack steps, although that's also port-5 only on Skylake so that doesn't help reduce p5 pressure.  `vpblendvb` on Skylake is 2 uops for p0/1/5, so it's worse for the front-end and needs a control vector.  If you're mixing the shuffling with enough compare and other work, hopefully p5 isn't the bottleneck.  (If order does matter, then pack pairs and use `vpermq` to fix up the final result.)

Comment: sounds good. would you mind writing an answer using this approach?